# R programming, correlation of quantitave variables with one qualitative variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, ordinal-data

I have a flat CSV file that has one column of student names, one column of grades (outcomes) coded as a factor A-F, and about 100 columns of test scores (independent variables) of various sorts, on different scales. I have recoded the grades to standard variables with mu = 0 and sigma = 1 (thinking that this may help). The student names are irrelevant and I have deleted them. The file has a header identifying the test scores my a code.

My problem is that I don't know which set of scores the grades were based on. I can correlate the scores with each other, but I don't know how to correlate the scores with the grades (the outcome/factor variable). I need to know which tests were used to calculate the grade.

I have a very strong belief that some combination of scores were used to determine the grade, but I don't know what the combination is, and I suspect that the scores were weighted differently (a score on an Art test counts some fraction of a score on a Math test.) The problem is that I need to reconstruct the grading rubric so that future students are graded similarly to past students.

What's the best way in R to reconstruct something like this? I'm moderately competent in statistics, but this is something far beyond anything I have encountered.

Thanks, CC.

Comment: Your response variable is ordered so you can use Ordinal Regression.

Comment: This does not sound like a specific programming problem. It looks like you need help choosing an appropriate statistical method to make the inference you want. We can't tell you what analysis is "correct" for your data; you must decide that.

Comment: +1 This kind of statistical "reverse-engineering" problem is always fun. It may be a bit of a computational challenge with 100 scores involved and almost certainly the solution (if it exists--a single numerical error made in computing the original grades can totally screw it up!) is not unique.

Comment: Do you have some kind of upper bound on the number of tests included in the grade? Do you know if some tests are more or less likely to be there, or any other information (e.g. something like 'the tests used shouldn't be "bunched up" in the list of 100 tests') that might help? I'd probably be tempted to take a Bayesian approach to this.